# Mobile Web - Things to consider?

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

So I am creating my first webpage catered to mobile browsers. What are some things to consider?

1. How do I get the resolution right for different devices (Blackberries, iPhones, iPads, etc.)? Is there a common method that people are using? Some sort of framework?
2. How do I prevent zooming (on most touch screen phones, you can zoom in by pinching)?
3. What are some other things to keep in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a ton of good practices to follow.  Here are a few:

1. make the content shorter and easier to read.  People can only scroll so much and read so much on a smaller screen size.
2. develop all your content in one single column.  Make the `width` flexible (100% or close to it) so that it expands to fill the screen  Do not make people horizontally scroll the page.
3. do not use a lot of a) scripts, b) css stylesheets, c) images.  These require lots of downloading and will increase the page load time and the cost for the user (as most people on mobile pay per KB for Web browsing).  Consolidate / gzip your files.
4. in your `css`, add extra `line-height` for easier reading.
5. in your `css`, add extra `letter-spacing` between numbers in phone numbers, for easier reading.
6. retain a link back to the full site, for those who want the full content.
7. include a back to top link at the bottom of the page, so users do not have to scroll all the way back up.
8. add padding to `a hrefs` so that it is easier to click/touch a link.
9. use `HTML5 form types` so that modern browsers will use the appropriate keyboards... http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html

Answer (score 3):

Just create normal web pages with liquid layout and let the browser take care of choosing an appropriate width.

If you know your pages will scale down nicely to mobile screen sizes, give the browser a clue that it can show the pages 1:1 without zooming by default. Include in your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

I would strongly recommend *not* attempting to disable zooming (`user-scalable=no`) as it's a useful feature that you gain nothing by blocking.