# CSS conventions for mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile

I'm developing a web page that would work on iPhone, iPad and other mobile devices.  I'm curious if there is a resource on best practices for CSS for mobile devices.

I have tried searching but come up with random sites [with tidbits of information](http://csswizardry.com/2010/01/iphone-css-tips-for-building-iphone-websites/)  but no comprehensive overview. I guess I could [buy a book about this subject](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230452) but that is not a sure thing either and I would imagine there are resources on the web out there I'm just not finding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think HTML5boilerplate does a very good job,

"[A best practice baseline for your mobile web app.](http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/)"

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this answer I gave a while back

[Mobile Web - Things to consider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161876/mobile-web-things-to-consider/6162058#6162058)

Also, you should check out

http://caniuse.com/

which outlines mobile support for HTML5 and CSS3.